# How to get results from google analytics if a custom dimension is not available for old data?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using google analytics api to fetch data from google to make my own dashboard. Recently, I have created a custom dimension for some purpose. There was a lot of data before the creation of custom dimension and i could access it using.

```
 gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': '300daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'metrics': 'ga:users',
    'dimensions':'ga:country,ga:region,ga:city,ga:date,ga:operatingSystem,ga:browser'
   ا

  })
  .then(function(response) {
//Dosomething
  })`
```

The code above returned the results for last 300 days. After creating CD i want to access the results for which it is defined as well as for which it isn't.

```
 gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': '300daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'today',
    'metrics': 'ga:users',
    'dimensions':'ga:dimension1,ga:country,ga:region,ga:city,ga:date,ga:operatingSystem,ga:browser'
   ا

  })
  .then(function(response) {
//Dosomething
  })
```

The response however shows 0 rows. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fetch data for which the custom dimension is not defined. You are querying based on the new custom dimension which is not available for data previously present. The only way you could do is fetch the data before the custom dimension was defined (if the data is not much) and reinsert it. This way custom dimension would be defined for that data.